# How do I benchmark the FPS of a CSS3 animation?

Tags: css, benchmarking

In WebGL, I can measure frames per second by recording the timestamps of when requestAnimationFrame occur.

How do I measure the frames-per-second of a CSS3 animation? I can measure how long the animation took, but how do I quantify the jank during the animation?

Comment: CSS3 animations are optimized by the device GPU. To quantify FPS of a particular animation you will need to add the elements and animation on a blank canvas. You can use Chrome's Dev Tools to view the FPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a webkit based browser do:

1.) `ctrl + shift + j` to bring up the dev tools.

2.) At the bottom you will see a tab called "Rendering", drag it up so you can see it's content.

4.) Put a check to "Show FPS" meter.

FPS metter should appear in your top right corner of the browser viewport, showing you the current fps and a graph.